# Can I play Fifa 15 UT on Windows 8 or Windows 10 using an external controller?

Tags: windows, windows-8, fifa-15

I recently installed the windows 10 Technical Preview, and downloaded FIFA 15 ultimate team from the Windows app store. I would like to know if it is possible to play the game with an external USB controller with this Operating  System or with Windows 8, 8.1

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, have you tried plugging one in?

Comment: I did. but its unresponsive though its working perfectly with my other games including fifa 14.

Comment: 10 currently has issues with Game pads under build 9926.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

I wondered also about this problem, but if you go to the windows site it says:  'Plus, if you have an external controller – don’t miss the chance to use it on the pitch for the first time. It’s your match to play!'

[Source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/games/fifa-15-ut/9wzdncrdjpkp)

Comment: Would you be kind enough to provide a link? As it stands, we can believe you, but having a link to it makes your answer even more solid! ;)

Comment: @Texenox I added the link, b0ss.